# MEAN stack: sanitize user input properly using express-validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sanitization

Using a MEAN stack with Node v11 and Express v4 as well as MongoDB and Mongoose, I was wondering, whether I've done everything I could to properly sanitize all user input which is send to my Node.js server and also stored in the MongoDB.

I employ express-validator and check all incoming data on route level through the chained .trim() and .escape() methods before processing. Example:

```
app.post('/whatever', [
  check('title').trim().escape(),
  check('age').trim().escape()
], (req, res) => {
  //return Book.findOne({title: req.body.title}).execAsync() // <---- is this safe now????
})
```

Down the road, I happen to perform several CRUD operations, such as searching for entries or changing user data. Is there anything else I could do before storing any data to MongoDB?

I've searched the web quite a bit but there is tons of information available and I feel if I considered every recommendation out there, my code would become tenfold longer and I am truly struggling to tell nice-to-have features from crucial security measures.